# rails 4 upgrade issue from rails 3.2 to rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upgrade

I got the following error after upgrading my app from rails 3.2 to rails 4

```
/xxx/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:32:
in `alias_method': undefined method `join_asset_file_contents' for
module `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper' (NameError)

from /xxx/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:32:
in `alias_method_chain'
```

how could I resolve this?

my Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'dalli'
gem "rmagick",:platforms=>:ruby
gem "rscribd"
gem "rubyzip", "0.9.9", :require => 'zip/zip'
gem "roo", "1.12.2"
gem "nokogiri", "1.6.0"
gem "spreadsheet"
gem "google-spreadsheet-ruby"
gem "mysql2", "0.3.13" ,:platforms=>:ruby
gem "delocalize"
gem 'rake', '10.1.0'
gem 'smurf'
gem 'json'
gem 'httparty' 
gem 'remotipart', '1.2.1'
gem "delayed_job"
gem "nested_form","0.3.2"
```

Comment: That's a nice error you have there.

Comment: is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: It's probably a gem that isn't compatible with Rails 4. Can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: Updated question with Gemfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smurf gem is not really rails 4 friendly.  You can set your own compressors in your `config/environments/production.rb` and make sure you aren't using the rails 3 compress = true setting.

```
# config.assets.compress = true --- commenting this out because it's deprecated.
config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier  
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
```

Uglifier and sass are gems you'd need to add back to your gemfile:

```
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
```

Comment: thanks for your input I have Updated your changes but the issue remains same.